# Search Button target= _blank jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a piece of javascript to pass a variable to a different site based on a radio button in a search form and I need to open the external link in a new window/tab. I did not write this piece of script it works as is but when I try to use any of the methods I've found online they either break the code or just return the url of the site instead of the external url

I've tried using window.open instead of window.location but that doesn't seem to work.

```js
var pacSearchURL = "http://sclends.lib.sc.us/eg/opac/results?qtype=keyword&query=",
  mobilePacSearchURL = "http://sclends.lib.sc.us/eg/opac/results?qtype=keyword&query=",
  catalogSearchPlaceholder = "Search Catalog",
  websiteSearchPlaceholder = "Search Site";

jQuery(function($) {
  $('body').on('submit', '#searchform', function() {
    var searchType = $('input[name=searchType]:checked', this).val();
    if (searchType == "catalog") {
      var windwoWidth = $(window).width();
      if (windwoWidth <= 520) {
        //if we are at a mobile resolution...
        window.location = mobilePacSearchURL + encodeURIComponent($("#s").val());
      } else {
        window.location = pacSearchURL + encodeURIComponent($("#s").val());
      }
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }).on('change', 'input[name="searchType"]', function() {
    if (this.value === "site") {
      $("#s").attr('placeholder', websiteSearchPlaceholder);
    } else if (this.value === "catalog") {
      $("#s").attr('placeholder', catalogSearchPlaceholder);
    }
  });
}(jQuery));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="search-submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
<input class="screen-reader-text" type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="search" />
<input id="site" class="search_rad" type="radio" name="searchType" value="site"><label for="site">Site</label>
<input id="catalog" class="search_rad" type="radio" name="searchType" value="catalog" checked="checked"><label for="catalog">Catalog</label>
```

I'd like the urls that are external to open in a new tab and when the site radio button is selected return target=_self

Comment: that's probably a pretty good reason not to randomly copy code you find on the internet. window.open is a function, not a property. you must call it as such. you cannot just assign a value to window.open.

Comment: I had to copy it from another library since they use the same code, but they don't open it in a new tab and this library wants it to open in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

use window.open() instead of window.location

```
 window.open(mobilePacSearchURL + encodeURIComponent($("#s").val()));
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Please don't use W3Schools as a reference. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. MDN is a far more reliable resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open